# AS3 - Using a For Loop to Update Multiple Points and Their Values in an Array

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs6

I'm a bit new with AS3 (but not really with coding) so please forgive my ignorance. I'm creating a small function that will be called by a Main Function to update the position of 52 Pointers that have the x and y position of multiple point objects (empty movie clips). It will also then update two global arrays with those values (one array for the x and one for the y).

The problem is, as there are 52 of them, and they will probably grow in quantity, I'd like to be able to use a FOR function to do it, but I can't seem to be able to figure it out.

I get this error: *Access of undefined property _point*.

Here is a piece of the code that dream about:

```
function happyFunc():void
{
    var avpointers:int = 52;
    var vpointx:Array = new Array();
    var vpointy:Array = new Array();        
    for (aa=0; aa<vpointers; aa++)
    {
        vpointx[aa] = _point[aa].x;
        vpointy[aa] = _point[aa].y;
    }
}
```

And this is the code that I'm stuck with...

```
function reallySadFunc():void
{
_point1 = localToGlobal(new Point(point1.x,point1.y));
//...
_point52 = localToGlobal(new Point(point52.x,point1.y));
vpointx[0] = _point1.x;
vpointx[1] = _point2.x;
//...
//oh god there are 104 lines of this why do I have to suffer
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is `point1`, `...` and `point52`? Are those `MovieClip` objects on the stage?

Comment: They are Point objects that represent a location. In my code, they are the global coordinates of point1 to point 52, which are MovieClips in a MovieClipt on the Stage.
For more on Points: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Point.html

Comment: How do you get these points? They cannot be on the stage so you have to create them somehow.

Comment: I add them by placing an empty MovieClip on the Stage. (e.g. press Ctrl+F8 and don't do anything), then name then "point1" (instance name)

Comment: Ah ok, so they aren't `Point`-s, they're `MovieClip`-s.

Comment: There are the point MovieClip-s and there are the _point Point-s. The point MovieClip-s are used to feed the _point Point-s with their x and y information. Which is what I need to update in the sub function whenever I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, I think this is what you need:

```
public static const CLIP_COUNT:int = 52;

// ...

private function happyFunc(parentClip:DisplayObjectContainer):void
{
    var vpointx:Vector.<Number> = new Vector.<Number>(CLIP_COUNT, true);
    var vpointy:Vector.<Number> = new Vector.<Number>(CLIP_COUNT, true);

    var clipPoint:Point = new Point ();
    var globalPoint:Point;

    for (var i:int = 0; i < CLIP_COUNT; i++)
    {
        var childClip:DisplayObject = parentClip.getChildByName("point" + 
            (i + 1).toString());

        clipPoint.x = childClip.x;
        clipPoint.y = childClip.y;

        globalPoint = parentClip.localToGlobal(clipPoint);

        vpointx[i] = globalPoint.x;
        vpointy[i] = globalPoint.y;
    }

    // do something with vpointx and vpointy - they're local variables
    // and will go out of scope unless you declare them as class members
    // or somehow return them from this function.
}
```

This function works by taking the parent display object (the one that contains the 52 movie clips - this could be the `Stage`) and iterates through them by getting each movie clip by name. The code assumes that your movie clips are called `point1`, `point2`, ..., `point52`.

To speed up the local-to-global coordinate conversion, two `Point` objects are created and then reused during the `for` loop to avoid creating many temporary `Point` instances.

Instead of using `Array`, use [`Vector.<Number>`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html#) - this class has better performance than `Array` does.